# Python equivalent of PropertyUtilsBean

Tags: python, apache-commons

I was wondering, is there a Python equivalent to Apache commons' PropertyUtilsBean?

**Edit:**
For example, I'd like to be able to make this assignment

```
x.y[2].z = v
```

given "y[2].z" as a string.
Please note, I'm asking just because I'd like to not reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Exactly what functionality of PropertyUtilsBean are you looking for?

Comment: Well the setProperty method, using a combination of nested and indexed formats to reference the property I'm interested in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need such a thing when there's [exec](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement)?

Comment: *Snap!* Didn't think of exec.. Damn Java legacy :D Thanks!

Comment: but remember exec("os.system('sudo rm -rf /')"), so you should be a little careful with exec :).  It's probably best to stick with setattr/getattr when you can get away with it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like [`setattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr)?

From its docstring:

> ```
> setattr(object, name, value)
> ```
>
> Set a named attribute on an object;
>   setattr(x, 'y', v) is equivalent to
>   ``x.y = v''.

Comment: Well yes I mean something like that, but more complex.. For example x.y[2].z = v :)

Comment: In that case, I think you need to use exec, as per Vinay's suggestion - even if I usually find exec usage quite a bad hack, I do not see any other possible easy solution.